# How to create, and copy the contents of a file in subprocess python

Tags: python, django, file, python-2.7, subprocess

How do I do a subprocess call to copy the contents of a file, say `hello.c`, to a file, `say 1.c`?

Firstly, How do I create a new file, like `1.c`? I tried

```
subprocess.call("touch", "1.c")
```

It give this error-

> TypeError: bufsize must be an integer

Comment: My question to you...why on earth would you want to do this? Just use the built-in python mechanisms to copy the file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a list of args, the second arg is the buffer size which you are passing a string for:

```
subprocess.check_call(["touch", "1.c"])
```

To copy a file in python you can use shutil.copy:

```
from shutil import copy

copy("foo.c","bar.c")
```

If you must use subprocess again pass a list of args:

```
subprocess.chexk_call(["cp", "a.c","b.c"])
```

If you get a non-zero return status  `check_call` will raise a `CalledProcessError`.

Comment: you should use `check_call()` instead of `call()` by default. *"Errors should never pass silently.  Unless explicitly silenced."*